# How to redirect an URL with optional unordered query string and keep it with Nginx

Tags: regex, nginx, redirect

I'd like to redirect an URL with different query string cases :

```
/onglet/lycee/alsace -> 
/onglet/lycee/alsace-est

/onglet/lycee/alsace?statut[]=sous-contrat&statut[]=catholique -> 
/onglet/lycee/alsace-est?statut[]=sous-contrat&statut[]=catholique

/onglet/lycee/alsace?statut[]=catholique -> 
/onglet/lycee/alsace-est?statut[]=catholique

/onglet/lycee/alsace?niveau[]=01-MATER&age[]=-3&statut[]=sous-contrat&statut[]=catholique ->
/onglet/lycee/alsace-est?niveau[]=01-MATER&age[]=-3&statut[]=sous-contrat&statut[]=catholique
```

As you can see the query string may contain one or more unordered arguments : `statut` can be at the beginning or not !

Also, the new URL `alsace-est` starts with the old one `alsace` that's why I can't use this :

```
rewrite ^/onglet/(.*)/alsace(.*)$ https://$host/onglet/$1/alsace-est$2 permanent;
```

I've tried to add a "?" in the first URL but it doesn't work : may be I have to escape it but I don't know how :

```
# Manage the first case
rewrite ^/onglet/(.*)/alsace$ https://$host/onglet/$1/alsace-est permanent;
# Manage the other cases : note the "?"
rewrite ^/onglet/(.*)/alsace?(.*)$ https://$host/onglet/$1/alsace-est?$2 permanent;
```

All I found on SoF are cases with well known parameters order and values and it's not my case :(

Comment: Try this: `rewrite ^(/onglet/.*/alsace)/?$ /$1-est permanent;`

Comment: @anubhava you have added an extra `/` at the beginning. Should be `$1-est` as the leading `/` is already captured.

Comment: Yes that's right, my bad. It should be `rewrite ^(/onglet/.*/alsace)/?$ $1-est permanent;`

Comment: @anubhava thank you, you lifesaver :) Just want to understand : how this could keep the query string ? I don't see any thing after the target URL !

Comment: Query string is passed over *as is* to target after redirect. I will mention this in my answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Nginx`, you may use this redirect rule:

```sh
rewrite ^(/onglet/.*/alsace)/?$ $1-est permanent;
```

Please understand that the query string is passed over as is to target after redirect.

**Rule Explanation:**

- `^`: Start
- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `/onglet/`: Match `/onglet/`:
  - `.*`: Match 0 or of any characters
  - `/alsace`: Match `/alsace`
- `)`: End capture group
- `/?$`: Match an optional `/` before end
- `$1-est`: Target URL uses back-reference to capture group #1 and adds `-est` at the end